# Linked images not found when moving a folder containing both the Word file and the images

Tags: microsoft-word, images

I have a folder with a Word (2003, opened in compatibility mode in 2010) file. All the images in this file are linked and reside in the same folder. When I move this folder to a different computer all the links are broken. When I select the image place holders and press F9 the link is restored. There must be a way to restore all links at the same time? Having to go through all the images one by one is pretty tedious...

Comment: @prrao This is embarassing: that was it. Make it into an answer for other baffoons like me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select ***all text*** to update all fields at once. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and *then* pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> should do the trick.